# Jquery text field populating from database on clicking select option

Tags: php, jquery, cakephp

I'am having a select option box,if i click on the select option,two other text below it should be loaded with data from database,based on select option id value.How to do this with
php and jquery or cakephp and jquery
thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

1. Capture the change event of the select box
2. do an ajax post of the info to a .php page (which will read the value, retrieve and echo the data from the db)
3. the ajax post will define a callback function that will be called on success (when the php is done echoing the data), which will populate the two fields..

so

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('your_select_box_selector').change(function(){
                $.getJSON( 'your_php_page.php', 
                           {selectVal: $(this).val()},
                           function(data){
                                      $('text1_selector').val(data.text1);
                                      $('text2_selector').val(data.text2);
                                          }
                          )

               });
});
```

and in your php you will need to read the selectVal url parameter we sent in getJSON call, and output something like this

```
{"text1": "text to go in the first text box", "text2": "text for the second text box"}
```