# get data from database using Ajax in cakePHP

Tags: php, ajax, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

Hello I need to retrieve data from database via an ajax call. I am unable to find any good resources for this. Any help would be great. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Edit in place with JQuery and CakePHP](http://cakebaker.42dh.com/2008/02/24/edit-in-place-with-jquery-and-cakephp/)

[Jquery text field populating from database on clicking select option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2032609/jquery-text-field-populating-from-database-on-clicking-select-option)

[CakePHP jQuery Ajax Helper](http://blog.loadsys.com/2009/05/01/cakephp-jquery-ajax-helper-easy-scriptaculous-replacement/)

[Tutorial - CakePHP Ajax "Quick Save" with jQuery](http://marcgrabanski.com/articles/cakephp-ajax-quick-save-jquery)